# Can one reset ink levels on an HP 6900 Series OfficeJet Pro?

Tags: printer

I have an HP 6978 OfficeJet Pro and I've searched and tried many methods for other HP printers. But, all the methods given seem to be for printers other than OfficeJet Pro versions.

I sure would like to find a method to clear and restart with full ink levels showing!

If my only choice is an ARC (Automatic Refill Chip with refill levels), then so be it.

Comment: Did you refill the cartridges?>>>may help you>>>https://bchtechnologies.com/blog/how-to-reset-hp-cartridge-chip/

Comment: These are aftermarket carts with the full level chip, so they would display ink levels like a new OEM cart. The carts were only half full, so I topped them off so-to-speak. I would just like to reset the level indicator in some fashion, whether I have to buy new chips or mess with the old ones. I'd just like to know what is possible with these OfficeJet Pro printers. I also have read your posts and videos too. But, there just is not much info on these particular printers.

Comment: When it comes to stinginess on cartridges, HP are the worst. It's why I don't recommend them, and advise people to NEVER upgrade the firmware. The only outcome of an upgrade will be more cartridge restrictions.